# Amavis and Postfix VirusMails

Tags: postfix, amavis

I have a postfix server with amavisd and a clamav scanner. I have encountered a situation where clamav has issued false positives and quarantined messages in /var/virusmails/

What is the simplest way of taking these mails and pushing them through the postfix que again. I believe the false positive was temporary and would like to retry sending them.

Is there a postfix que directory I could place the files in?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not trivial in my experience, but maybe someone has a great idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your using amavisd-new, you can simply run the amavisd-release command, passing it the quarantine ID of the mail in question.  It will take care of removing the email from the quarantine and injecting the email into Postfix, bypassing any content filtering.

You can find out the details at http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#quar-release.

Comment: looks exactly like what I'm looking for however the command doesn't seem to exist on my system. amavisd-new-2.5.3 is the running version.

Comment: I checked the 2.5.3 release (still available for download) and the amavisd-release app is there.  Try downloading the package from http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/#download and installing amavisd-release yourself.

Comment: it looks like it is in the CentOS packages for 2.5.3-2 and I have 2.5.3-1! Just unlucky but pushing the mails to another system running a more recent version and unfreezing them from there with that command has done the trick!